# How to create a dictionary of multiple keys and pairs in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list with repetitive keys and multiple value pairs as such:

```
abc abc.txt
abc abc-xyz.jpg
abc abc.978.png
efg efg.txt
efg efg-xyz.jpg
efg efg.978.png
```

I want to create a dictionary like this.

`dict = {'abc':'["abc.txt", "abc-xyz.jpg", "abc.978.png"]', 'efg':'["efg.txt", "efg-xyz.jpg", "efg.978.png"]'}`

How do I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can possibly use `defaultdict` to do this simply.

```
from collections import defaultdict
lines = string.split('\n')
d = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines:
    key, value = line.split(' ')
    d[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to initialize each key with an empty list [] and then, use append when adding a new item. 
For example:

```
list = """abc abc.txt
abc abc-xyz.jpg
abc abc.978.png
efg efg.txt
efg efg-xyz.jpg
efg efg.978.png"""

dict = {}

for line in list.split('\n'):
    (key, value) = line.split(' ')
    if not key in dict:
        dict[key] = []
    dict[key].append(value)

print(dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = ['abc abc.txt', 'abc abc-xyz.jpg', 'abc abc.978.png', 'efg efg.txt', 'efg efg-xyz.jpg', 'efg efg.978.png']
new_s = [i.split() for i in s]
new_data = {a:[d for c, d in list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(new_s, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'abc': ['abc.txt', 'abc-xyz.jpg', 'abc.978.png'], 'efg': ['efg.txt', 'efg-xyz.jpg', 'efg.978.png']}
```